# What is the most efficient way to use Jackson to continually parse a bunch of strings?

Tags: java, jackson

Let's say I have an iterator of Strings. I want to create an Iterator of Java objects, and efficiently convert from one to the other. I'm not sure what the best way to do this is...the docs I've seen seem to create a new parser per String, but I'm not sure if there is an easier way?

Thanks!

Comment: Quick question: by iterator of Strings, you mean a sequence of basically distincts JSON documents? Or something different?

Comment: Yes, except instead of a file, distinct Strings...but yeah, that's basically it

Answer (score 1):

Usually I would recommend just creating new `JsonParser` (and it does work), but if JSON Strings are very short, alternate method would be to create equivalent of `StringReader` that works on List or array of Strings -- sort of like `java.io.SequenceInputStream`, but one that works on Strings.
This should have bit lower overhead, as long as you take care NOT to concatenate Strings, but just represent `Reader` over equivalent of concatenated sequence.

Jackson can then read a sequence of JSON values using such Reader -- either explicitly one by one, or more conveniently, using `ObjectMapper.readValues(...)` (or methods from `ObjectReader`, instance of which you can create using various factory methods `ObjectMapper` has): something like

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyReader reader = new MyReader(listOfStrings);
MappingIterator<BeanType> it = mapper.reader(BeanType.class).readValues(reader);
while (it.hasNext()) {
  BeanType bean = it.nextValue();
}
```